# Does loading unloading iframes in a webpage affects its history?

Tags: javascript, browser, iframe, yui, browser-history

I have a web page that on click of buttons loads another web page in iframe in a div. On clicking the launch button this is what is done

- the src attribute of iframe is set to url of required webpage. I have noticed this increments the history.
- the div is shown, which essentially shows the iframe as well

On clicking the close button

- the div is hidden, which essentially hides the iframe as well
- the src attribute of iframe is set to about:blank, deleting the iframe object doesn't help

Now this close part increases the browser history and I can see the iframe in history list. Why is this happening and how can I avoid this?

I found the solution. Instead of setting the source attribute one can replace the location with a new url. Example: `iframeobject.set contentWindow.document.location.replace(url);`

Comment: Instead of setting the src attribute, which adds a history entry, just delete the iframe object completely.

Comment: d'oh, dint think about it :( will try this :)

Comment: this doesn't help. I still see the history being incremented

Answer (score 1):

a way to fix the history thing is to not use an iframe but an object and change its data attribute to whatever target. it won't add to history because it's like changing the source of an image. you just have to specify `type="text/html"` in the object tag

`<object type="text/html" data="http://www.google.com/" width="500" height="500"></object>`

Comment: looks like ie and ff not supporting it. http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_object.asp